# After installing Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS, restarted, doesn't boot to Ubuntu, but Dell Assistant runs check

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, usb-installation

I have a windows 10 installed Dell laptop Inspiron 15 3558 (2016). I made a Ubuntu boot USB and planned to replace Windows 10 completely for Ubuntu. After the installation process, and prompted to restart, the laptop restarts to Dell Support Assistant, which run check for memory because it said the laptop wasn't boot properly. After let it complete its check, the laptop just shut off by itself. At first I mistakenly booted Ubuntu installation with the secureboot still on.

After that same scenario, I discovered from other posts that I supposed to turn it off. I did, and rerun the installation. But this time I saw that the install shows Ubuntu was discovered, I chose and complete the reinstall. Then I was prompted to remove the boot medium and press enter to restart into Ubuntu. Yet the same scenario happened again.

I also tried to leave the boot usb, only to have it boot back to GRUB2 with options to try Ubuntu, install, OEM install, and check disc for defects. I will post screenshots if you want to see any.

Comment: Make sure SecureBoot is still off. Boot the Live USB and select Try Ubuntu. Then start `gparted` and make sure to delete all partitions from your hard disk. Then start the Installer and let it use the entire disk. Tell us the outcome.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Though It's complicated. I need to switch back from UEFI to Legacy after the first installation. I think UBUNTU needs an environment to successfully install, and have it boots. So I need to install it at first from USB drive via UEIF boot. Then switch to Legacy boot to install it into the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Before installlation, change BIOS boot mode to UEFI boot with
  secureboot off.
- Choose try UBUNTU via GRUB2.
- Search and start gparted.
- Via gparted, delete all partitions (thanks to WillemK).
- Proceed with the install.
- Restart, and go back to BIOS boot mode settings.
- Change BIOS boot mode to Legacy with secureboot off.
- Wait for UBUNTU installation (again).
- Proceed with the install, and restart.
- Done!

Lesson of the day: don't use live boot USB, not as reliable as dish. And don't use windows 10; It's a pain to switch to other OS.